# Formatting data array with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, postgresql

I am trying to get data from PostgreSQL with ruby and store them into an array, for that I have a small script:

**Script :**

```
require 'pg'  

conn=PGconn.connect( :hostaddr=>"192.168.111.136", :port=>5432, :dbname=>"sentinel_poc",:user=>"sdn_mehdi", :password=>'skyline123')  

res = conn.exec("SELECT dns_name FROM dns_table group by dns_name").to_a  

a_dns = []  

res.each { |r| a_dns << r }  
puts a_dns.join(",")
```

**The outcome is :**

```
{"dns_name"=>"youtube.com                                       "},{"dns_name"=>"stackoverflow.com                                         "},{"dns_name"=>"cisco.com                                         "},{"dns_name"=>"facebook.com                                      "},{"dns_name"=>"yahoo.com                                         "},{"dns_name"=>"onf.com                                           "},{"dns_name"=>"safe.com                                          "},{"dns_name"=>"linkedin.com                                      "},{"dns_name"=>"amazon.com                                        "},{"dns_name"=>"google.com                                        "},{"dns_name"=>"java.com                                          "},{"dns_name"=>"live.com                                          "},{"dns_name"=>"rails.com                                         "},{"dns_name"=>"postgresql.com                                    "},{"dns_name"=>"hp.com                                            "},{"dns_name"=>"wikipedia.org                                     "}
```

What I need is just the name of each domain name! Something like `{"youtube.com","google.com","java.com","rails.com","hp.com"}`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The result you expect (`{"youtube.com","google.com",...}`) cannot exist in Rails, it looks like a Hash but with only keys (or values?). Did you mean something like an array of the dns names? or an array of hashes containing `:dns_name => string_of_dns_name` ?

Comment: something like an array of the dns names !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your code only, and doing small changes, I guess following will work for you

```
a_dns = []  

res.each { |r| a_dns << r.values[0].strip }  
puts a_dns
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need :

```
res.flat_map(&:values)
# or if you have hashes having size more then 1, then use the below
res.map { |h| h["dns_name"] }
# to strip leading and trailing whit spaces
res.map { |h| h["dns_name"].strip }
```

Comment: @midobAck Please be more specific, what doesn't work?

Comment: I tried all your suggestions but I get the same outcome as before !

Comment: @midobAck Got your point.. do `res.map! { |h| h["dns_name"].strip }`